# How to write a Core Data predicate for objects which are related to an object in a to-many relationship

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data

`EntityA` has a to-many relationship to `EntityB` (and `EntityB` has a to-one relationship to `EntityA`). I have an array of `EntityB`s (or more accurately, I have an `NSArray` that contains instances of `NSManagedObject` which represent `EntityB`). I want to create an `NSFetchRequest` that will fetch all `EntityA`s that  have a relationship to at least one of the `EntityB`s in the array. How do I write the predicate for this fetch request?

The following works, but I think it is sub-optimal; it's hard to grok and I'm sure there must be a better way of expressing this:

```
NSArray *entityBs = ...;
NSMutableArray *containsEntityBSubPredicates = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSManagedObject *entityB in entityBs) {
    [containsEntityBSubPredicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN entityBs", entityB]];
}
NSPredicate *containsEntityBsPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:containsEntityBSubPredicates];
```

I've also tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
NSArray *entityBs = ...;
NSPredicate *containsEntityBsPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %@ in entityBs", entityBs];
```

Am I missing a simpler solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there with your predicate, just switch the parameters:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY entityBs in %@", entityBArray];
```

Look at Apple's example code with `IN` [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215891) for further explanation.